# Наст и настлать

Tags: этимология

Можно ли отнести слова наст и гл. настлать к этимологически однокоренным?

Answer (score 1):

На уровне древнерусского языка нельзя, а вот в далёком индоевропейском прошлом - да, если Вас это устроит.

Г. Цыганенко считает, что *наст* развилось из  * *надтъ* - "корка на снегу" после изменения  **дт** в **тт** и **ст.** Это сущ. могло быть образовано с помощью суффикса -т-ъ (как наседтъ / насест) от слова над "сверху", которое раньше было наречием, а теперь употребляется в качестве предлога. Есть ещё мнение, что слово *настъ* могло быть образовано присоединением прист. *на-* к корню *ст-* от "стоять" в глаголе стать. Тогда наст первоначально как бы "стоящий на..." - "твёрдая кора на снегу".

Настлать - стлать развилось из др.-рус. *стьлати*, стелю. Праслав.*stьlati  развилось из и.-е. основы *stel-, кот. содержит тот же и.-е. корень *sta-, что и в *стать*.